# find the inorder traversal of the tree and print them all by negating every alternate number

Tags: c++, binary-tree, inorder

For example:

```
         1
      /      \
    /         \
  2             3
 /  \         / \
 4   5       6   7
```

Inorder traversal output: 4 2 5 1 6 3 7

Expected output:  4 -2 5 -1 6 -3 7

code for inorder is

```
Node * func(struct Node * root){
if(root!=NULL)
{
func(root->lChild);
cout<<root->nodeValue<<" ";
func(root->rChild);
}
return NULL;
```

}

Comment: We assume you can't put all items in a list and then negate, right?

Comment: what is the question? your title reads like the answer to the question that you didnt ask, as @alseether says, simply first get all numbers and then print them with alternating signs

Comment: Good luck on your homework, but really if you want help you should post what you've tried, and the exact problem you have encountered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you might have to do , add a additional argument to keep track of alternate sign, something like following :

```
Node * func(struct Node * root, int& signV ){
  if(root!=NULL)
  {
    func(root->lChild, signV);
    cout<<root->nodeValue * signV <<" "; signV *= -1 ; // Change sign here
    func(root->rChild, signV);
  }
  return NULL;
}
```

[`See Here`](http://rextester.com/UZFG69121)